# Why does "set VAR=value" not work in bash?

Tags: bash, shell

I am having problem setting a environment variable correctly.

These are first few lines of my deploy.sh:

```
if [[ -z ${PEM_PATH+x} ]]; then
    printf "Please set the PEM_PATH environment variable\n"
    exit 1
fi
```

This is my terminal output:

```
bash-3.2$ set PEM_PATH="/Users/Elasticsearch/Desktop/ec2-poc.pem"
bash-3.2$ ls
Jenkinsfile     bps-dashboard.iml   mvnw            node_modules        package.json        src         webpack.config.js
README.md       deploy.sh       mvnw.cmd        package-lock.json   pom.xml         target
bash-3.2$ set PEM_PATH="/Users/Elasticsearch/Desktop/ec2-poc.pem"
bash-3.2$ echo $PEM_PATH
/Users/Elasticsearch/Desktop/ec2-poc.pem
bash-3.2$ sh deploy.sh
Please set the PEM_PATH environment variable
bash-3.2$
```

What am I doing wrong here ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`set` does not set variables in bash (or other POSIX-family shells) -- it configures shell option flags, or changes the active argument list (`$1`, `$2`, and so on).

You can run any of the following to define `PEM_PATH` as an environment variable (without the `export` or the `-x` argument to `declare` or the use of `set -a` it would be a regular, non-exported shell variable):

- `export PEM_PATH="/Users/Elasticsearch/Desktop/ec2-poc.pem"` -- both defining and exporting the variable with a single command.
- `PEM_PATH="/Users/Elasticsearch/Desktop/ec2-poc.pem"; export PEM_PATH` -- first defining `PEM_PATH` as a regular shell variable, then promoting it to an environment variable
- `declare -x PEM_PATH="/Users/Elasticsearch/Desktop/ec2-poc.pem"` -- using the bash-only extension `declare` to define `PEM_PATH` as an exported variable.
- `set -a; PEM_PATH="/Users/Elasticsearch/Desktop/ec2-poc.pem"; set +a` -- using `set -a` to make all variables exported to the environment by default; then setting the variable; then turning off that flag.

Comment: That seems to work. Thanks !

Comment: np. We may well actually have a duplicate, in which case I'd be converting this answer to community wiki (disowning ownership/reputation from it) anyhow.